# How do I solve a sum of products optimization problem using DQCP with cvxPy?

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy, convex-optimization

In cvxPy's examples on [DQCP explainer](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dqcp/index.html) page the following example is shown to be a type of problem solvable with DQCP:

```
import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable(pos=True)
y = cp.Variable(pos=True)

product = cp.multiply(x, y)

assert product.is_dqcp()
```

Can someone give ideas on how to solve this for a vector variable? My problem has constraints, but here's the sample code that shows where the primary issue is:

```
import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable(2, pos=True)
y = cp.Variable(2, pos=True)

product = cp.sum(cp.multiply(x, y))

assert product.is_dqcp() #this fails since sum of products isn't DQCP
```

Tried DGP and DCCP as well, but can't find the right way to reformulate the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The objective function you have defined is bilinear. The traditional way to solve this problem is linearize the objective functions via [McCormick envelopes](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=McCormick_envelopes). I personally havent used [this package](https://github.com/shaoyuanxun/MCPy), but it looks promising